# "Cannot resolve symbol" for modelAttribute in .jsp file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a web application in Spring Boot. I would like to map all inputs of a web form to a Java object called UserRequest. I have tried this using a .jsp file and use modelAttribute but get an error for "modelAttribute="userRequest""  in my .jsp file:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/" modelAttribute="userRequest">
```

"Cannot resolve symbol 'userRequest'". I am using IntelliJ. I have no idea why this is occuring (I know there is a similar thread for a Spring application, but their solution does not work for me). See more details below.

How do I fix this?

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <head>
        <title>Find a Dance Event</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h2> Find your next Dance Party</h2>

<form:form method="POST" action="/" modelAttribute="userRequest">
    <form:label path="profession">Profession:</form:label>
    <form:select path="Dance Event" items="${danceEvents}" /><br/>
    <form:select path="Dance Style" items="${danceStyles}" /><br/>

    <form:label path="street"> Street:</form:label><br>
    <form:input path="street"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml_:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>findadanceevent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>findadanceevent</name>
    <description>findadanceevent</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mockito extention -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

RestServices.java:

```
 @Service
    public class RestService  {
    
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String showForm(Model model){
            UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
             model.addAttribute("userRequest",userRequest);
    
            List<String> danceStyles = Arrays.asList("Kizomba", "Salsa", "Bachata");
            List<String> danceEvents = Arrays.asList("Festival", "Class", "Workshop");
            List<String> distances = Arrays.asList("2_5km", "5km", "7_5km", "10km", "over10km");
    
            model.addAttribute("danceStyles", danceStyles);
            model.addAttribute("eventType", danceEvents);
            model.addAttribute("distances", distances);
    
            return "index";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/")
        public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("userRequest") UserRequest userRequest) {
            System.out.println(userRequest);
            return "register_success";
        }
```

UserRequest.java:

```
public class UserRequest {

    private String street;

    private String typeOfEvent;
    private String danceStyle;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }


    public String getTypeOfEvent() {
        return typeOfEvent;
    }

    public void setTypeOfEvent(String typeOfEvent) {
        this.typeOfEvent = typeOfEvent;
    }

    public String getDanceStyle() {
        return danceStyle;
    }

    public void setDanceStyle(String danceStyle) {
        this.danceStyle = danceStyle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserRequest{" +
                "street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", typeOfEvent='" + typeOfEvent + '\'' +
                ", danceStyle='" + danceStyle + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't placing the `UserRequest` in the model so how should the JSP be able to find it?

Comment: Thanks M. I have just added the line "model.addAttribute("userRequest",userRequest);" to the "showForm" Method in the RestServices.java class. However, the issue still persists. Have I missed anything else?

Comment: Do you get an error at runtime or in Intellij?

Comment: I get an IntelliJ error for the .jsp file but the application does run. However, http://localhost:8080 gives 

"Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."

Comment: You still aren't adding it and the error is probably due to something else, check the server logs.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you maybe give me a hint where or what I need to add please?